# LAMP in sandbox

Tags: 12.04, lamp

I am using Denwer on MS Windows.
Is there a ready-made solution, providing LAMP in the sandbox on Ubuntu 12.04?
I want LAMP isolated from the outside network and doesn't require an internet connection.
If not, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "sandbox".  Do you mean isolated from the outside network?  Do you mean installed in a manner that doesn't require an internet connection?

Anyways, I don't believe there's a preinstalled image, but installing the LAMP stack on Ubuntu is trivial.

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Comment: I want LAMP isolated from the outside network and doesn't require an internet connection.